# Specific pages as always https and some others always http

Tags: php, ssl, https

I want a few pages on my website to be always https and other pages to be always http.

If someone visits the https page with http://, he should be redirected to https and vice versa, if someone visits the page meant to be over http:// with protocol https:// he should be redirected to http version

Answer (score 1):

Use [$_SERVER['HTTPS']](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) to detect if the user is already on an https connection, otherwise redirect using a 301 - Moved Permanently (all future requests should go to the intended https URL). Example for redirection is [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/php-redirect/).